# Unit testing for backend and services methods calls with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, frontend

I started working with tests, more specifically with Jasmine, and I'm having some difficulty to test if the backend and some services methods are being called.

So basically I'm calling the **forgotPassword** method when the formulary is submitted and I was wondering how can I properly check if the API (**apiSendPasswordResetLink**) and the services methods (**showLoader**, **showAlert** and **navigateTo**) are being called as expected.

```
async forgotPassword() {
    try {
        console.log("1");
        this.loadingService.showLoader();
        console.log("2");
        await this.userService
            .apiSendPasswordResetLink(this.form.value['email'])
            .toPromise();

        console.log("3");
        this.utilitiesService.showAlert(`We've emailed you a link to reset your password. Please check your mail box and spam.`);

        console.log("4");
        delay(1500);
        this.navigationService.navigateTo('/login/auth');
        console.log('5')
    } catch (err) {
        this.utilitiesService.showAlert(err);
    } finally {
        this.loadingService.hideLoader();
    }
}
```

The test:

```
it('should submit email to reset password after submitting formulary', () => {
    component.form.setValue({
      email: 'test@test.io',
    });

    const loadingService = TestBed.inject(LoaderService);
    const userService = TestBed.inject(UserService);
    const utilitiesService = TestBed.inject(UtilitiesService);
    const navigationService = TestBed.inject(NavigationService);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#button');

    spyOn(component, 'forgotPassword').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(loadingService, 'showLoader');
    spyOn(userService, 'apiUserSendPasswordResetLink');
    spyOn(utilitiesService, 'showAlert');
    spyOn(navigationService, 'navigateTo');

    // Submitting form
    fixture.debugElement
      .query(By.css('form'))
      .triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);

    expect(component.form.valid).toEqual(true);
    expect(button.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.forgotPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(loadingService.showLoader).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(userService.apiUserSendPasswordResetLinkGet).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(utilitiesService.showAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(navigationService.navigateTo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Every time I run and / or debug the test, I have the error

> Expected spy navigateTo to have been called.

But the console never prints "3", which means **showAlert** is also not being called and I should also have the same error regarding showAlert spy to be called, but I don't.

I don't know if this problem has to do if the await call to the API or something else. I would like to know how can I fix it, so all the test can pass as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please try this : spyOn(userService, 'apiUserSendPasswordResetLinkGet').and.returnValue(of({result: "some expected result"})); And of() method should be imported from rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a spy on `UserService#apiUserSendPasswordResetLink`, without any spy strategy, it defaults to doing nothing. However, in your `forgotPassword` method, you are chaining the response of the call to a Promise wrapper and awaiting the resolution. Since `apiUserSendPasswordResetLink` is not invoked, I'm guessing that the promise is never resolved and the test gets stuck.

One simple way to resolve the issue is to add a strategy to the spy so that it returns a value:

```
spyOn(userService, 'apiUserSendPasswordResetLink').and.returnValue('whatever');
```